# How can i check to see if a row has been selected?

Tags: java, if-statement, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, selected

I have a button click event on which i am getting a column value, if a `Table` row is selected. But if i don't select the row and click the button i get the error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-1` my question is how can i check to see if a row has been selected pseudocode: `if(Row == selected) { execute }`

java code i have:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try 
        {
            int row = Table.getSelectedRow();
            String Table_click = (Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());            

           //... implementation hire   

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }        
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stop and think logically about your problem before you're tempted to post. Take a break from coding if you need to -- once you take a break, the solution to the problem often presents itself in short order.

```
int row = Table.getSelectedRow();

if(row == -1)
{
    // No row selected
    // Show error message
}
else
{
    String Table_click = (Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
    // do whatever you need to do with the data from the row
}
```

Comment: just to add information:
getSelectedRow Returns the index of the first selected row, -1 if no row is selected.

Answer (score 1):

When no row is selected, [`getSelectedRow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29) returns `-1`.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   try {
      int row = Table.getSelectedRow();
      if (row > -1) {
         String Table_click = (Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
         //... implementation here
      }
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if row > -1 then you know a row has been selected.
see: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29)